# How to restore images

Tags: magento2, product-images

I ran one of overly aggressive scripts which deleted the product images.

I did have a backup, so how can I restore them?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I copied the backup images back to ~/httpdocs/pub/media/catalog/product.

Then, the follow command regenerates the images for the site.

```
php bin/magento catalog:images:resize
```